# Why does the TikZ code not accept addition and subtraction operations but accept multiplication and division operations?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code, but I don't understand why the TikZ code does not accept addition and subtraction operations but accepts multiplication and division operations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
 \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.2cm,fill=blue!20] () at ({\the\numexpr 
    72*(\i-1) \relax}:2cm) {\i};
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,fill=red!20] () at (
   \i*360/5:1cm ) {\i};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It has to go through the following processing `{\the\numexpr 72*(\i-1) \relax}`, but `\i*360/5` is Ok.
At least addition and subtraction are more basic operations than multiplication and division, why is there such an inconsistent design?

**Edits:** Many thanks to Cabohah for correcting my mistaken idea. But I have another example, why does the second code show an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
  \node[draw,circle] (\i) at (72*\i-36:1cm) {$\i$};
}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4} {
  \draw (\i) -- ({\i+1});
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Package pgf Error: No shape named `1+1' is known. }...

**It seems that TikZ does not accept any operation at this time.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is not the subtraction but the `(…)`, because this is *shape syntax*. So using `(\i)*360/5` would also be wrong. But you don't need `\numexpr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5} {
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=0.2cm,fill=blue!20] () at (
  {72*(\i-1)}:2cm) {\i};
  \node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,fill=red!20] () at (
   \i*360/5:1cm ) {\i};
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using the extra grouping is enough.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for correcting my mistaken idea.

Comment: Sorry. See my second code. The problem seems to be different here.  A series of error reports: Package pgf Error: No shape named `1+1' is known. }...

Comment: @licheng The second example is different from the first one, here you want indeed the named nodes, but the *argument* of `(…)` is not calculated it is only an expanded string, so `(\i+1)` just would result in `(1+1)`, `(2+1)` etc. If you want the result of a calculation, you should do the calculation before, e.g., `\tikzmath{\j=\i+1;}`, and use the new variable. However, because this is a new question you should not mix it into the already answered question, but really ask a new one.

Comment: `(1)` is a coordinate (or a node) called `1`; that's very different from `(1,1)` (which is a coordinate with `x=1` and `y=1`). So `({\i+1})` is looking for a node/coordinate *named* the expansion of `\i` concatenated with `+1`.